# ggplot, ggplotly, scale_y_continuous, ylim and percentage

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a graph where the y axis is in percentage:

```
p = ggplot(test, aes(x=creation_date, y=value, color=type)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=type)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("breach"="red","within_promise"="green","before_promise"="blue")) +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(as.numeric(as.Date('2016-05-14'))),linetype="dotted") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)

ggplotly()
```

[image]

Now I would like to set the y axis superior limit to be 100%

```
p = ggplot(test, aes(x=creation_date, y=value, color=type)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=type)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("breach"="red","within_promise"="green","before_promise"="blue")) +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(as.numeric(as.Date('2016-05-14'))),linetype="dotted") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
  ylim(0, 1)

ggplotly()
```

But result is the same as the previous plot, the y axis limits are the same.
It works when I don't put the y axis to be in percent:

```
p = ggplot(test, aes(x=creation_date, y=value, color=type)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=type)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("breach"="red","within_promise"="green","before_promise"="blue")) +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(as.numeric(as.Date('2016-05-14'))),linetype="dotted") + 
  ylim(0, 1)

ggplotly()
```

[image]

Moreover using ggplotly when I set the y axis to be in percent when I put my mouse on a point of the graph the value is not in percent:

[image]

Comment: can you add your dataset to your post?

Answer (score 19):

I'm aware it's been a whle since you asked, but you could use `limits` inside `scale_y_continuous()`, like this:

`scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits=c(0,1))`

Answer (score 6):

Minor suggested edit to the response above:

It seems that you have to specify the limits within the `scale_y_continuous` call *prior* to setting the values as percentages:

`scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), labels = scales::percent)`

Comment: Not for me - it works fine on my graph specifying labels first and limits second, as @dudu wrote.

Answer (score 2):

As you have not given the dataset, I am making my best guess.

You need to give `limits` option within `scale_y_continuous`. `ylim` as you see, does not override the aesthetics set by `scale_y_continuous`. You need to use one function to change aesthetics of y-axis. Use `ylim` or `scale_y_continuous`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue here and neither solutions worked for me. It's clear that we can't combine `scale_y_continuous` with `ylim`. Setting the limit parameter within `scale_y_continuous` caused some erros. However, as suggested in the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) we can use the function `coord_cartesian()` in combination with `scale_y_continuous`. The final code would be something like this:

```
...+
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.50, 0.75)) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```